# Git mirror with gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

how do I mirror a git repository to Gerrit?

I will do this:

[git repository for libdrm] -> my gerrit <-> developers

Gerrit download changes from freedesktop git repository.
Developers clone repository from gerrit and push into gerrit.
Developers never pushes changes to main repository.

I have created new project with gerrit.
I download repository:

```
git clone http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/mesa/drm.git
```

I will push this repository to gerrit, but I can't because I have got errors:

```
remote: ERROR:  In commit ced219ebbd3b266ac8326223bad62f994907ae6b
remote: ERROR:  committer email address chris@chris-wilson.co.uk
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  The following addresses are currently registered:
remote: ERROR:    xxx@example.com
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
remote: ERROR:  http://mygerrit-server/#/settings/contact
```

I have permisions for all.
How I can add mirror to gerrit?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the 'Forge Committer' and 'Forge Author' access permissions.  This tells Gerrit to ignore that you aren't the author or committer of the commits you are pushing. http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/access-control.html#category_forge_author

Comment: On our gerrit the forge committer and forge author flags are BLOCKED globally. Any idea how to rewrite the committers for all commits at once?

Comment: You can use `git filter-branch` to batch changes to commits.  One quick example is at https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/